# How can I get LineB to be on the right of ObjectA no matter where the camera is looking at ObjectA from?

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I have an ObjectA(cylinder) and a LineB in THREE JS. I'd like LineB to always be to the right of Line A no matter where the camera is viewing ObjectA from. So this should always be ObjectA's and LineB's positioning regardless of the viewing angle of the camera to ObjectA(cylinder):

```
ObjectA     LineB
 ________  
 |      |     |
 |      |     |
 |      |     |
 |      |     |
 |      |     |
 |______|     |
```

Here is my current attempt

```
function LineGraph(props: {cylinder:[number, number, number], path:[number,number,number,number][]}) {
  const cylinderTubeRadius = 5; //radius of the cylinder (0 axis for lineplot)

  const cylinderLoc = new THREE.Vector3(...props.cylinder);

  const { camera } = useThree(); // reference to the threejs camera

  // access camera position
  const currentPosition = camera.position;

  // access camera rotation (rotation is euclidean)
  const currentRotation = camera.rotation;

  //This initialises a line in the scene
  var points = props.path.map((point: any) => exampleLineCalc(point));
  console.log("points", points);
  const lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);

  // this allows us to change the line on each render frame.
  useFrame(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      const pos = exampleLineCalc(props.path[i])
      points[i].copy(pos);
    }
    lineGeometry.setFromPoints(points); // update the line with new points
  });

  return (
    <mesh {...props}>
      {/* @ts-ignore */}
      <line geometry={lineGeometry}>
        <lineBasicMaterial
          vertexColors={false}
          color={"#FFDA29"}
          attach={"material"}
        />
      </line>
    </mesh>
  );
}
```

How can I accomplish that with the camera position, camera rotation, cylinder radius?